# How to intercept keyboard shortcuts in GNOME

Tags: c++, c, linux, keyboard

I want to write an application which will intercept some keyboards sequences (like those in Emacs – "C-c C-c") and run some function.

How can I do this in GNOME?

On which level I should do that (kernel, X11, window manager)?

Comment: Can you clarify your goal? Do you want global shortcuts (Captured no matter which window has focus) or application shortcuts? Am I correct in assuming that you want to capture sequences of key combinations? ("C-c C-c" having a significance beyond "Do the action for C-c twice in a row")

Comment: I want to write appliccation with no window which will capture global sequences of combinations (similar to this in EMACS but for GNOME), for exapmple when I'm in GEdit and run "C-c C-u" I want it to run function uppercase on selected text in GEdit, and when I type "C-c f" it shuld run function wich run firefox.

Answer (score 1):

To run a commond on a certain key press you can configure that in metacity or compiz (depending which you're running).

For metacity run `gconf-editor`, go to `/apps/metacity/keybinding_commands` and under there you will see `command_1` etc. In there you set the command to run, and then in `/apps/metacity/global_keybindings` you set the keybindings to match. The key for `run_command_1` runs the command for `command_1`, and so on.

For compiz you want to run `ccsm` ("compiz config settings manager") and use the Commands plugin to configure it, in more or less the same way.

For performing an action in Gedit, as far as I know there is no way to do that, unless there is an existing keyboard shortcut for the command you are issuing. In that case you may be able to find an app that translates "C-c C-u" into the right shortcut for Gedit. But I've never done it.