# Book about programming in X on Linux

Tags: linux

Anybody knows a book about X11 (or XOrg) programming on Linux.

Comment: Do you want to create graphical user interfaces? In that case you should really be looking at the different window systems around (GTK, Tkinter, Qt, etc).

Comment: I want to know more about X to know if it's possible to intercept keyboard events between X Server and X clients. It's related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/3647095/387194.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a famous book at Amazon related to X programming, kind old also. But as ikanobori said you should look for GTK or Qt books. But also if your intention is to do low level X programming maybe the book can help (you will get crazy also :)

The link to the book: [http://www.amazon.com/Window-System-Programming-Applications-Motif/dp/0131238035/ref=sr_1_9?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1284216372&sr=1-9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131238035)

There is other books also (and older), but you probably don't want to program in motif, right? =P